# Click On TreeView Item Opens Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have the following XAML Code:

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="TreeViewWithViewModelDemo.LoadOnDemand.LoadOnDemandDemoControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewWithViewModelDemo.LoadOnDemand"
    >
    <DockPanel>
      <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
              </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>

        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

      </TreeView>
    </DockPanel>
  </UserControl>
```

This works fine as far as clicking on the item in the treeview and the items expanding and contracting.

What I would like to do in addition to this is to have a separate window open when an item in the treeview is double-clicked.  Is there a way to bind this commmand action to this XAML and leave what is currently there as is?

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'command action'...do you mean that you have an `ICommand` implementation that opens the window already?

Comment: Yes, I have an ICommand implementation but I'm not sure how to bind it to the treeview in a double-click...

Comment: Hi Steve, Any ideas on how to bind this ICommand to this TreeView?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an EventSetter for your style:

```
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDown"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
```

Then handle opening your window in the event handler.

Comment: I'll try this...  Is there only one event "MouseDown" and no "Click" or "Double-Click"?

Comment: I believe TreeViewItem supports MouseDown and MouseLeftButtonDown, but not double click directly. However, you can check the "ClickCount" property of the MouseButtonEventArgs in your handler to see if it's a double or a single click.

Comment: When I try to add the line <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDown" /> I get the error "An unknown error occurred while trying to navigate to event handler.  Please rebuild your project and try again".  I've tried to rebuild it numerous times and it still gives me this error.  Any ideas?  I try to "right click" and follow "Navigate To EventHandler" and get the same error.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I've seen that problem in Visual Studio before. You'll just have to write the handler method yourself in the code behind. It won't create it for you like it does when it's not in a style.

Comment: @AnnSanderson: TreeViewItem has a [double click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx), just check the docs of a class to see all the events.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `InputBindings` property as below:

```
<TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path.To.YourCommand}" />
    </TreeViewItem.InputBindings>
</TreeViewItem>
```

These have the advantage of not needing a code behind (which is needed by Matts answer) and make use of the `ICommand` you have already written.

I'm not sure if you'll be able to set these in a style though; you might need to do something like set the `Template` of the `TreeViewItem` and then use the `InputBindings` within the `ControlTemplate`